# to replace the name with original name in kdb q

Tags: kdb

there are two tables

Names- with columns - OriginalName, username

```
Names:([]OriginalName:("Arnab ahmed";"Arnab ahmed";"Arnab ahmed (TY)"); username:("ancdv";"ancdv4";"id001"));
```

| OriginalName | username |
| --- | --- |
| Arnab ahmed | "ancdv" |
| Arnab ahmed | "ancdv4" |
| Arnab ahmed (TY) | "id001" |

myTable - with column - CustomerName

```
myTable:([]CustomerName: ("Arnab ahmed";"id001";"ancdv";"Arnab ahmed (TY)") )
```

| CustomerName |
| --- |
| "Arnab ahmed" |
| "id001" |
| "ancdv" |
| "Arnab ahmed (TY) |

-> Names table has fixed length say maximum of 20 rows with values in it -> myTable has n number of values say 2000 rows with customernames in it

I need to check if the CustomerName from myTable is present in Names table(in any of the columns) if present then change the CustomerName to Original Name(from Names table)

I need to check if the customerName is present in
the output should be

| CustomerName |
| --- |
| "Arnab ahmed" |
| "Arnab ahmed" |
| "Arnab ahmed" |
| "Arnab ahmed" |

How to achieve the above

Comment: Are you sure about the expected output? Maybe the second and fourth lines should rather be "Arnab ahmed (TY)"?

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to your previous question, so modifying the solution from there. Example tables:

```
Names:([]OriginalName:("Arnab ahmed";"Arnab ahmed";"Arnab ahmed (TY)"); username:("ancdv";"ancdv4";"id001"));
myTable:([]CustomerName: ("Arnab ahmed";"id001";"ancdv";"Arnab ahmed (TY)") )
```

Creating a mapping for `CustomerName` to `OriginalName` and then check if a mapping exists and use it if so:

```
q)map:1!ungroup exec([]CustomerName:get each Names;(count'[Names])#'enlist each OriginalName)from Names;
q)select CustomerName:?[0<count'[OriginalName];OriginalName;CustomerName] from myTable lj map
CustomerName
------------------
"Arnab ahmed"
"Arnab ahmed (TY)"
"Arnab ahmed"
"Arnab ahmed (TY)"
```

Note that your example output is incorrect as `"id001"` and `"Arnab ahmed (TY)"` should both map to `"Arnab ahmed (TY)"`.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what is Arnab ahmed (TY) and why is not present in your final result?

If I understood well, after executing this SQL query, the **myTable** will be updated with the desired result, where CustomerName is replaced by the OriginalName when a match is found.

Do not forget to **create a backup** as this query will update your tables:

```
q('update CustomerName:?[CustomerName in Names`CustomerName; Names`OriginalName; CustomerName] from myTable', { myTable, Names }, (err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log(result.myTable);
  }
});
```

Comment: This won't work as `Names` and `myTable` have different lengths.